# How to filter rows that match the subsequent row based on some column variables in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame similar to this one below

```
Firstname<-c('Anne','Anne','Mich','Mich','Peter','Darren')
Middlename<-c('','C','','','T','T')
Lastname<-c('Jones','Hooper','Blake','Blake', 'Ramirez','Wilson')
lidnum<-c(0001,00001,00003,00003,00004,00004)

df<-data.frame(Firstname,Middlename,Lastname,lidnum) 

  Firstname Middlename Lastname lidnum
1      Anne               Jones      1
2      Anne          C   Hooper      1
3      Mich               Blake      3
4      Mich               Blake      3
5     Peter          T  Ramirez      4
6    Darren          T   Wilson      4
```

These are profile pairs of individuals who match on the `lidnum` column I want to identify people that match on the `Firstname` and `Lastname` so that the result looks like the following. Basically how do I get profile pairs that match on `Firstname` and `Lastname`?

```
3      Mich               Blake      3
4      Mich               Blake      3
```

Comment: Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:  ```df %>% group_by(Firstname, Lastname) %>% nest()``` or ```group_split(df, Firstname, Lastname)```

Comment: `df %>% group_by(Firstname, Lastname) %>% filter(n() > 1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df[with(df, as.logical(ave(lidnum, Firstname, Lastname, FUN = function(x) length(x) > 1))),]
#  Firstname Middlename Lastname lidnum
#3      Mich               Blake      3
#4      Mich               Blake      3
```

Comment: `subset(df, ave(lidnum, Firstname, Lastname, FUN = length) > 1)` a bit shorter.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
df[duplicated(df[c("Firstname", "Lastname")]) | duplicated(df[c("Firstname", "Lastname")], fromLast = TRUE), ]

  Firstname Middlename Lastname lidnum
3      Mich               Blake      3
4      Mich               Blake      3
```